# How to set KeyStore and trustStore path within a jar

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, keystore, truststore

I have keystore and truststore files which i want to keep inside a executable jar. In IDE i put these file in a /main/resources/ and was getting a path from there by using ClassLoader, But within a jar file can only be load as a stream. Is there any possibility to get a path of these file as i need to create it SslContextFactory which only get a absolute path rather than a stream?

Comment: No, Solution is something different from what i am looking for. This will work within an IDE but not if i put and load these file within a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no other way rather than create a temp file and delete deleteOnExit() using commons-io.

```
public static File stream2file(InputStream in, String PREFIX) throws IOException {
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, ".jks");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }
    return tempFile;
}
```

Comment: do you set the result of this as a SystemProperty?  If so, where do you do it?  In Main?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but I think you can do:

```
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("something.jks"));
```

Comment: Resource class is in which package?

Comment: @user565 org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource

Comment: By using jetty util(Version: 9.3.0.M1) getting a problem in making connection i don't know why it given error may be Charset is setting or something else. Here is a error with above solution: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: __UTF8_CHARSET
 at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection$SendUpgradeRequest.run(UpgradeConnection.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2

Comment: @user565 Check if you use the same version for all jetty jars.